# Redirect to url based on user role in Websphere

Tags: websphere, redirect, user-roles

I need to direct a user with a certain User Role to a specific URL. Can this be done in WebSphere? If so, how?

Comment: I just used HttpServletRequest#isUserInRole("Role") in the bean upon login to redirect them to a proper URL

Answer (score 0):

You can use isUserInRole() as below where req is HttpServletRequest

```
if (req.isUserInRole("myRole")){
        ...

}
```

For more details:
[Developing with programmatic security APIs for web applications](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_web.html)